# Occasionally Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, unix

I have a very unusual error condition that I can't seem to find the solution to.  I'm hoping someone out here in StackOverflowland can help.  Before you just look at the title and say "your CLASSPATH is wrong," read on!

I work with a server-based Java application that utilizes a number of third-party libraries.  The particular library that I'm getting the error with is a file transfer library.  Part of the functionality of the application allows the user to connect to remote servers (FTP, SFTP and FTPS) and send/receive files.

One of our customers is using the application and occasionally gets a "*Class Not Found Exception*" (or more specifically, "*No Class Definition Found*") when attempting to connect to a remote host.  What's weird is that they don't get it all the time.  They have sent me logs that show a successful connection and then another one which shows this error.  There was no restart of the server between the two and both connections are to the same host using the same connection settings.

What would cause a "*Class Not Found Exception*" to occur occasionally within a Java application on a class that has already been successfully used?  I've contacted the third-party vendor and they are just as puzzled.

I wasn't able to determine anything from the stack trace, but since it was requested, here it is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.configuration.ConfigurationLoader (initialization failure)   
   at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:139)    
   at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.SshThread.a(SshThread.java:93)     
   at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.SshThread.<init>(SshThread.java:73)    
   at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon.startTransportProtocol(TransportProtocolCommon.java:515)
   at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.SshClient.connect(SshClient.java:593)
   at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ssh.SCPClient.connectSSH(SCPClient.java:1137)
   at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ssh.SSHFTPClient.connect(SSHFTPClient.java:920)
   at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.async.internal.ConnectTask.connect(ConnectTask.java:154)
   at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.async.internal.ConnectTask.run(ConnectTask.java:216)
   at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.async.internal.FTPTaskProcessor$b.run(FTPTaskProcessor.java:590)
```

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace.

Comment: Maybe you missed some libraries that are used only under certain conditions...

Comment: @Ksenia The entire third-party library is in a single JAR file.